# Parsing option arguments in terminal using getopt_long in C

Tags: c, terminal, getopt-long

I'm just having a problem when parsing my option arguments through terminal. 
When executing my c file, I can only have one option which is the file name. I can enter the file name with two options (a short option and a long option):

- -f
- --filename

and they both need the file name as argument.
When I execute the program with "-f" and "--filename", it works fine but when I test "-filename", it doesn't give me error saying "the usage is ..." and it counts the argument of this option as one of the non-option arguments of main (I don't know if I expressed it well)
Can anyone help me with that? How can I handle this? How to tell the user this is not the correct option? 
This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>

static struct option longopts[] = {
    {"filename",  required_argument, 0, 'f'},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int res;
    int indexptr;
    char *filename;
    while ((res = getopt_long(argc,argv,"f:",longopts,&indexptr)) != -1)
    {
        switch(res)
        {
        case 'f':
            filename = optarg; // the file is now in optarg 
            break;

        default: /* '?' */
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <[-f/--filename Filename]> <D> <U>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html) good concise example of how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `-filename` (with one dash), most getopt implementations will treat it the same as `-f ilename` (which is not an error). If you had printed out what it thinks the filename argument is you would have seen "ilename".

Comment: So can you tell me how to handle that? saying this is not a correct option ? thanks

Comment: @jamal How are you going to handle `-f <non_existent_file>`? It's basically the same case as that. I imagine you would `stat` or `open` the file, check whether that succeeds and print an error message if it fails.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum. I fixed the problem :)

Comment: @jamal Good to hear. Suggest you post your changes as an update to the question for the benefit of future readers.